use material ui with Preact
I have this web component created with Preact and I'm trying to use Material ui to style it. Reading Preacts documentation, https://preactjs.com/about/libraries-addons/, it claims to have support for material ui. However when Im running the app locally it gives an error as material ui has a dependency to react.
I installed mui using:
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
Then I copied an empample from mui docs to make the moste basic slider:
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import Slider from "@mui/material/Slider";

export default function ContinuousSlider() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: 200 }}>
      <Slider disabled defaultValue={30} aria-label="Disabled slider" />
    </Box>
  );
}

I get the html for the slider in my shadow-dom but it's commpletely unstyled so I can't see it without inspecting the code.
I also tried usint preact-material-components but the result was the same plus I'm a bit reluctant to use that since it hasn't benn updated in four years.
The project is set up with Vite and my vite.config.js looks like:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import preact from '@preact/preset-vite';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [preact()],
});

EDIT:
I tried to make a really simple reproduction of the files contained here:
I have this web component built with Preact and I'm tryng to add Mui styling to it. It works fine until I turn on the shadow root.
Basically I have the following files. 'index.html':
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark" />
    <title>Slider</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="module" src="/index.jsx"></script>

    <slider-component></slider-component>
</body>

</html>

index.jsx:
import register from "preact-custom-element";
import Slider from "./src/Slider";

register(Slider, "slider-component", [], { shadow: true });

and Slider.jsx
import Slider from "@mui/material/Slider";

export default function ContinuousSlider() {
  return <Slider defaultValue={30} aria-label="Disabled slider" />;
}

Then I have jsconfig.json which looks like:
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2020",
        "module": "ESNext",
        "moduleResolution": "bundler",
        "noEmit": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": true,

        /* Preact Config */
        "jsx": "react-jsx",
        "jsxImportSource": "preact",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "paths": {
            "react": ["./node_modules/preact/compat/"],
            "react-dom": ["./node_modules/preact/compat/"]
        }
    },
    "include": ["node_modules/vite/client.d.ts", "**/*"]
}

and package.json that looks like:
{
    "private": true,
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.5",
        "@mui/material": "^5.15.15",
        "preact": "^10.13.1",
        "preact-custom-element": "^4.3.0",
        "react": "npm:@preact/compat",
        "react-dom": "npm:@preact/compat"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@preact/preset-vite": "^2.5.0",
        "eslint": "^8.56.0",
        "eslint-config-preact": "^1.3.0",
        "vite": "^4.3.2"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "preact"
    }
}

plus vite.config.js that looks like:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import preact from '@preact/preset-vite';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [preact()],
});

The problem occurs when I change from { shadow: false } to { shadow: true } in index.jsx

Have you followed the aliasing instructions? Preact supports React libs through preact/compat, but you need to set it up. preact-material-component is indeed unmaintained and shouldn't be used.

It's setup with Vite and the documentation sais vite handles the aliases by defualt. My vite.config.js looks like this:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import preact from '@preact/preset-vite';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
 plugins: [preact()],
});


That's set up correctly then. What's the error you're seeing, as you haven't posted it? How are you rendering your ContinuousSlider component?

I'm getting the html correctly in the shadow dom with all the typical Mui-classes but there's no styling applied.

I even get the style tag in the head  It's not applied though.

As it seems the problem wasn´t that PRect wasn't able to use Mui. The problem is that the Mui styling is applied in the head-tag and not in the shadow dom. It I turn off the shadow dom then my Mui-elements are styled. So I still need to figure out how to get the Mui-styling in the shadow dom.

I'd help if you could provide a full reproduction, as it's unclear how you're rendering it or what aliasing errors you're still seeing.

Thankyou. I tried to update the post with some more code.

I got it working following Material ui's document on Shadow DOM, useing CacheProvider and createCache from emotion.
I also had to register the web-component with {shadow: false}and then attach a shadow to it that I could use in the cache. Finally I rendered my App inside the CashProvidertargeting the newly created shadow root element.
